# Sharepoint Online videos stopped working - blank screen and no player

Tags: sharepoint-online, video, asset-library

I have several videos in a document library. Modern view - all mp4 - Read permissions for all internal users - only used for intranet content. I used the document library instead of the asset library/list format to avoid all the extra folders. BUT, I also have a smaller asset library that I used to test when everything stopped working. 
Last week - everything played in the browser (Edge, Chrome, and FireFox).
Monday - blank screen. No player controls - nothing. Not even an error message.
They just stopped playing!!

Comment: Welcome to [SharePoint S.E.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)! Can you check to see if either you had a system update or if any drivers were updated? Additionally, please check the developer screen (by pressing f12, or right clicking) then navigate to the document library and try to play one of them. Are there any console errors? I'm asking because some people may refer to "no error messages" to mean on the GUI instead of console. What other changes could have happened over the weekend? Thanks!

Comment: My computer doesn't show any updates over the weekend. There is one recurring-type error. The GUID changes... but here it is

 HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/training/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed/isFollowed?siteId={05f9e952-a181-4331-9915-e8741e218e73}&webId={c1c72327-99b5-43c6-bd2a-9c0da6ac46ba}&url=https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/training
 (forgive my formatting... totally new at this)

Answer (score 1):

ok... I've lost my mind. Today - everything works again. Maybe Microsoft hates our domain. Thanks anyway